# How to except '/nova' route if I have 'any' route that matches with any request

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am going to make own CMS based on laravel nova. Now I'm making a 'Pages' functional. I will put my pages as rows of the table `pages` that will contains the `url` column. In the end of my `routes/web.php` file, I have the route that matches with any route:

```
Route::get( .... );
Route::post( .... );
Route::get('/{page}', 'PageController@myRouter')->where('page', '[A-Za-z0-9_\-\/]+');
```

In the `myRoute` method I will catch an url and try to find the page with this url in the database; All works fine, but when I type `<domain_of_my_site>/nova` to getting admin panel, I have 404. Because of, nova's routes are included later than my route-for-any-request. So, how to fix it? How I can put this

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'PageController@myRouter')->where('page', '[A-Za-z0-9_\-\/]+');
```

really in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with generic slugs in my routes file. I managed to limit the pattern for the slugs to alpha-numeric characters (including dashes, hyphens and slashes*) but exclude the Nova routes (`nova-api` and `nova-vendor`) as well as the Nova path to the admin panel (`nova`).

This is how the `routes/web.php` file looks like:

```php
Route::get('/{page}', 'PageController@myRouter');
```

And the pattern for `{page}` in the `RouteServiceProvider` in the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file:

```php
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('page', '^(?!nova|nova-api|nova-vendor).[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+$');

    parent::boot();
}
```

*) Please note that this pattern also allows slugs like `/page/one/two`.